# How to make wireframe mode in 2.9 look like 2.8's version

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

Blender 2.9x version changed the wireframe mode and it personally is much harder for me to tell what I'm looking at. Previous versions have full wireframes and I would like to know if there is a way to change it  to look like 2.8x's wireframe. The 2.9x version wireframe is attached below.
[image: What my 2.90.1 wireframe mode looks like, very hard to see anything]

Comment: Have you tried the wireframe check-box in Viewport Overlays?

Comment: yeah, i tried turning that on but it didnt seem to change anything in any display mode from what i could see

Comment: Weird, it should! From your pic, you're in wireframe mode, but it looks like your wireframe setting is set very low, possibly even zero. There is a slider in the Viewport Overlays controlling wireframe density. What is it set to?

Comment: It is set to 1. I also tried messing with that slider and turning wireframe on for the object in the Viewport Display options but nothing changes at all, its always just a thin outline of the model.

Comment: went back into the model; turning on wireframe did turn it on, but only in sculpt mode, still not proper wireframe in any other mode which is what I'm aiming for

Comment: I think I found something... If you have a Subdivision Surface modifier on that object, turn off "Optimal Display" in the Modifiers settings

Comment: Still didn't change anything sadly. I looked into similar threads and there appears to be an issue with AMD GPUs displaying some things properly in 2.9x and it looks to be my issue as i am using an AMD GPU. I think it's something either Blender or AMD has to solve, but thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: You're welcome, if I stumble across anything else I'll post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch to wireframe mode, click the top right viewport shading dropdown menu and change the X-Ray value to your liking, the higher it is the higher the opacity of the wireframe will be.
[image: xray default value]
[image: xray max value]